# Hiera 5 command not working to display required output

Tags: puppet

Hiera 5 command not working

I am unable to find issue in hiera as it is not working i am tried to understand the working of hiera but its showing same result all time.
I have hiera.yaml as:

```
---
version: 5
defaults: 
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data

hierarchy:
  - name: "Test Message"
    path: "test/%{testname}.yaml"

  - name: "Common"
    path: "common.yaml"
```

first its not looking for data directory but looking for hieradata directory
once added the files common.yaml and test/value.yaml file and run the command

```
hiera msg environment=development
```

above command return "Common file"
here i have already setup the development environment and common.yaml contains

```
---
msg: "Common file"
```

and test/value.yaml

```
---
msg: "Demo test"
```

but i again run the command

```
hiera msg environment=development testname=value
```

it returns "Common file"

please tell me what is wrong here so i am not getting "Demo test" as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hiera command line utility should not be used any more and you should use `puppet lookup` instead ([docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/hiera_automatic.html#using-puppet-lookup)).

If you fix that up, you should be able to correctly lookup data using these commands:

```
▶ FACTER_testname="" puppet lookup msg   
--- Common file
```

and:

```
▶ FACTER_testname=value puppet lookup msg
--- Demo test
```

Note that you mention `environment=development` but your Hierarchy doesn't seem to know about environment so I ignored that.

Comment: Thanks got it really appreciate your help